# Python Pandas Merging two columns but drop duplicated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have encountered a problem with following example dataframe in Python Pandas.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| c | c |
| d | e |
| g | g |

I would love to have something like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | ab |
| c | c | c |
| d | e | de |
| g | g | g |

Could someone please help? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom aggregation with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html), using [`dict.from_keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to remove the duplicates while keeping order, and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate:

```
df['Column C'] = df.agg(lambda r: ''.join(dict.fromkeys(r)), axis=1)

# or limiting to specific columns:
cols = ['Column A', 'Column B']
df['Column C'] = df[cols].agg(lambda r: ''.join(dict.fromkeys(r)), axis=1)
```

Or, if only two columns:

```
df['Column C'] = (df['Column A'].add(df['Column B'])
                  .where(df['Column A'].ne(df['Column B']), df['Column A'])
                  )
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B Column C
0        a        b       ab
1        c        c        c
2        d        e       de
3        g        g        g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to iterate on each row of pandas then use [`pandas.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and `''.join` to get the result.

```
df['Column C'] = df[['Column A', 'Column B']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()), axis=1)
```

---

```
  Column A Column B Column C
0        a        b       ab
1        c        c        c
2        d        e       de
3        g        g        g
```